# buttonMode and useHandCursor property in DataGrid doesn't work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

If I set the properties of "`buttonMode`" and "`useHandCursor`" to true in `DataGrid`, it does not work as I expect. Only if I move the cursor to the edge between two rows, the hand cursor displayes.

What I expect is that no matter where the cursor is moved, it should always show hand cursor.

The following the `itemRenderer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Label 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import valueObject.Employee;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void{
                super.data = value;
                var employee:Employee = value as Employee;
                this.text = employee.lastName;
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Label>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should set useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" **mouseChildren="false"** on your ItemRenderer class. On DG you can then set useHandCursor="false" so hand cursor is not shown on DG borders and/or scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you are hoving over an "area with data" it's not the DG that's deciding what the cursor should be, it's whatever is being used as the ItemRenderer. So you should be setting the properties on the renderer, not the DG.

Comment: I tried as you said, but still not exactly what I want. I use itemRenderer in DG, and set "buttonMode" and "useHandCursor" both in DG and itemRenderer to ture, but only when I move the cursor to the edge between two rows, the hand cursor can show. You can see the attched.

Comment: What's the item renderer you are using? Remember its the display object at the top of the stack at the point the cursor is that's deciding what the cursor should be. If your item renderer is complicated you might have to set the properties on a few things.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, please tell us what `itemRenderer` you are using (i.e. a custom mx:Label) and maybe also post some code:

In theory, it works like this:

1. Create e.g. a custom mx:Label and name it "MyLabel.mxml"
2. Set the buttonMocde and useHandCursor properties.
3. Assign "MyLabel" to the itemRenderer property of your DataGrid. Be careful to adjust for paths information if using nested folders..

Comment: the itemRenderer is customized mx:Label

Comment: Did you try to do as I described?